# jQuery image toggle

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Having issues using jQuery to toggle from one image to another. Not getting any console errors, so I'm not sure what the issue is - any suggestions would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <main>
        <div id="bathroom" class="switch"> </div>
    </main>
```

CSS:

```
#bathroom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 42%;
    height: 100%;

}

.switch {
    background-image: url('women.png');

}

.switchOn {
    background-image: url('men.png');
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#bathroom').click(function(){

$('#bathroom').toggleClass('switchOn switch');

});
```

You can see it here in action, though not much is happening. I had the women.png showing for a little bit, and then it just disappeared.

https://jsfiddle.net/c1g47o5u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, except of two tiny things:

- jquery is not included in your jsfiddle
- the div with the click event has no width

so put a

```
width: 200px;
```

into the `#bathroom` to make the div clickable.

Here is a fixed version of the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2optdrbp/1/

Comment: this is the code in my head

`<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Bathroom Break</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>`

I'm linking jquery.. does this still not use it?

Comment: jquery is not included in the jsfiddle, seems you included it in your application

Comment: ah, gotcha! would i just use no repeat in the css to just show the one image?

appreciate the help!

Comment: either that, or better set the height of the div to the height of the image instead of `100%`: